# Async queries to neo4j from javascript

Tags: javascript, neo4j

Up to now, 
I managed to have my function that run the queries being able to return a result immediately.
so the structure of my functions where

```
var session = driver.session();
return session.run([QUERY]).then(result=> return result.record.map ....)
```

I now have a bigger query and maybe for that reason, I end up having the query function return a Premise 
I switched then to an async function with the following structure

```
 var session = driver.session();
await session.run([QUERY]).then(result=> results= result.record.map ....)
return results
```

But then I get *regeneratorRuntime is not defined* at runtime in the console of the browser.

As environment config, I have the one of the sample movies-javascript-bolt-master

Thank You

Comment: `results= result.record.map` is that a typo?

Comment: There is code after that to interpret what the run of the query return.
And as per sample on neo4j site, in case of an aync call the value is stored in a variable (results) that then is returned at the end of the async function

Comment: I took as sample the code from https://observablehq.com/@nhogs/neo4j-driver-for-javascript in the section "Run a query and return result records (the Promise way):"

Comment: I adapted my code to reflex the sample for the 4.0 neo4j :https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/session-api/asynchronous/
but it is anyway the same as I get a value of the function that is returned asynchronously

Comment: Are you using Babel? The *regeneratorRuntime* error is about Babel (a library that helps convert the JS code for older runtimes). It looks like it can't convert the async/await syntax to a generator function

Comment: Hello @GuerricP ... I am lost as not familiar with async libraries for Javascript. Right now, I am looking at this github page https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#consuming-records-with-promise-api ... it is clearly stated that "the Promise way, where the complete result is collected before we act on it:" ... but unfortunately when I put this code in a funciton it returns a Promise (pending) and not the object itself ...I think I should not need to use babel and polyfill (I tried btw but nt being familiar I got lost on the way and my code was no more compilable by npm)

Comment: Can you show your actual code, or at least similar code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Hi All, I broke my code by trying to migrate bable version. As soon as I will have it restored, I will create a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need `async`/`await` in order to make your code work. This is just syntaxic sugar but the mechanism under the hood is exactly the same, and it does not allow to do more things (an `async function` is just a function returning a `Promise`). It just allows to make the code more compact and readable.

If you still want to use this syntax, you'll have to update Webpack and Babel to their latest versions, and update their configurations (use [babel-presets-2017](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-preset-es2017) which allows to transform async/await to [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/function*) in order to enable older runtimes to run your code).

The error code you have is related to this particular feature of Babel (you could also disable it completely).

Comment: Thank You Guerric ... my code in fact works, in the sense that there are no errors ... as long as I don't try to use the data returned by the neo4j query ... how I get the value from the Premise (which on the Chrome console looks pending)?

Comment: @BrunoC Asynchronous implies to provide a **callback** to execute code when the asynchronous operation is complete. You have to identify what is the callback in your environment. For example if you're building an API with Express.js you would do `res.send(result)` when `result` is available. If you share more code, or explain what you want to do with the result, then I'll be able to provide a concrete answer

Comment: The Promise is not a result of an APi request but the result of a DB query against a neo4j graph DBMS... for a misterious reason, one of the queries I run return its result as promise.
The query is run calling my APi that is an interface for querying the DB:
api.searchLogicalLayer()

I tried 
var temp=api.searchLogicalLayer().then(function(value) {
        console.log('Async success!', value);
        return(value);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Caught an error!', err);
        });;
console.log(temp)
This last command will return a Promise

Comment: @BrunoC my actual question is: where are you running this code, and what do you want to do with Neo4j results?

Comment: I need to transform it into JSON to feed d3

Comment: Here's a fiddle for the problem I am facing .... https://jsfiddle.net/thebruuu/jpoes295/4/

Comment: In your example everything that uses the result of the asynchronous random number generation should go in `.then()` callbacks which can be chained if needed (e.g: `.then(...).then(...).then(...).catch(...)`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210129/discussion-between-bruno-c-and-guerric-p).